# Reportviewer 2010, overlapping text boxes

Tags: reportviewer

**Visual Studio 2010 with reportviewer -** 
overlapping elements texboxes, rectangles, pictures **PROBLEM**.

---

I need a form that contains small fonts and fields with colored background. The only way to do it I see placing textboxes over frames or over pictures. It does not work.

If I use body background to display an empty form, it gives me only quality of `96 dpi` which is not enough to ptint this background properly.